# sleeping connections vs constant polling SQL

Tags: c#, sql, performance, t-sql, polling

What has more of a toll on efficiency, a sleeping SQL connection or constant database polling?

I'm trying to decide between using SqlDependency or SqlCacheDependency to monitor changes to our database. The SqlDependnecy creates a sleeping connection which I've read doesn't really create that much of a strain, but isn't it bad to leave an open connection? I've also read that SqlCacheDependency uses SqlDependency but you can specify polling time which makes me think it acts a bit differently.

If polling is a better route, at what rate of polling does the effect become less efficient?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of efficiency are you interested in?

Comment: Trying to see which will slow down the application the least. Not looking for which is more efficient in reporting changes quickly. I guess to elaborate further, I am storing my appSettings in a table instead of web.config. I want to be able to reflect changes to the table. Since the amount of data is small, I don't really have a preference for cache or static variable. My focus is more on which method of notification will have the highest toll on the application